# No suitable ClassLoader found for grab wenn starting from SCM jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy-grape, groovyclassloader

Why if i run pipeline script there is no problem, and if i run it from SCM i get

> No suitable ClassLoader found for grab

How can I fix this?